# Why does useEffect run multiple times?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using useEffect to fetch data from an API. No matter what I do, the useEffect runs multiple times.

```
  const [productDetails, setProductDetails] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      `url`
    )
      .then(results => results.json())
      .then(results => {
        setProductDetails(results);
      });
  }, []);
```

I read that you don't set state in useEffect, so I tried another approach:

```
const [productDetails, setProductDetails] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAsync();
  }, []);

  async function fetchAsync() {
    // await response of fetch call
    let response = await fetch(
      `url`
    );
    // only proceed once promise is resolved
    let data = await response.json();
    // only proceed once second promise is resolved
    setProductDetails(data); // setting state after fetching data
  }
```

In both cases, when I `console.log(productDetails);` I get the results back multiple times, so I guess useEffect runs multiple times. I thought about a bug in useEffect and tried with the old `componentDidMount()` but it's always the same. Results are coming back multiple times.

Is there a 100% correct way to set up an API call and getting the results back only ONCE?

Comment: `I read that you don't set state in useEffect, so I tried another approach` is not correct

Comment: You are doing it right. It might be your parent component that is mounting twice/multiple times that is causing this component to run `useEffect()` multiple times

Comment: is your data received from fetch an array?

Comment: As the others said, there is nothing wrong by setting the state in this hook. Please show the parent component

Comment: Parent component is also just a component which fetches the categories and passes down the Product ID so that I can fetch the correct product. 

@Tick20 yes, my data is coming in as an array.

Comment: By the way, does every useEffect in the component trigger a seperate render? I've seen people setting up multiple useEffects in one component to fetch data or push data to the navigationsOptions. If every useEffect causes a sperate rerender, isn't that pretty bad?

Comment: The blank `useEffect` is similar to `componentDidMount` - it's run when the component is first mounted. If you have a parent component making an API request and doing the same stuff, that is making a request, changing, and bubbling that command down to its children.

Comment: I understand, but I'm not sure how to avoid it. I guess it's bad to have an unnecessary rerender?! Would it be better to make the request at the top level of the App and pass the data down to the components via React Context?

Comment: Ok. I did some testing. It seems that a loading state causes it to rerender. After setProductDetails(results); I set a setLoading(false) and that causes that my results are coming back twice. Why is that and where would I put setLoading(true) and setLoading(false)? Thanks

Comment: @hapfr did you find a solution to this issue or the true cause?

Answer (score 3):

I'm quite sure the problem is outside the code you have posted.

I guess that the component that contains this useEffect is re-created for some reason. Maybe even because the parent component (or the parent-parent ...) is re-created.

Answer (score 0):

Please you must check whether this API already called by the parent component.
In my case, I was calling the same API in the child component as well, and as a result, the useEffect was calling multiple times.